# Unable to find activity, but its defined in manifest

Tags: android-manifest, activitynotfoundexception

I've searched and searched, but nothing pushes me in the right direction.

Here the MainActivity:

```
package com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

Intent Showframe = new Intent(this, FrameLayout.class);

public void ShowIt(View view) {

        startActivity(Showframe);

}
}
```

Here the FrameLocationActivity:

```
package com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;


public class FrameLayout extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

/**
 * GoogleApiClient wraps our service connection to Google Play Services and provides access
 * to the user's sign in state as well as the Google's APIs.
 */
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

private PlaceAutocompleteAdapter mAdapter;

private DelayAutoCompleteTextView mAutocompleteView;

private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_GREATER_SYDNEY = new LatLngBounds(
        new LatLng(-34.041458, 150.790100), new LatLng(-33.682247, 151.383362));

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.frame_location);

    // Construct a GoogleApiClient for the {@link Places#GEO_DATA_API} using AutoManage
    // functionality, which automatically sets up the API client to handle Activity lifecycle
    // events. If your activity does not extend FragmentActivity, make sure to call connect()
    // and disconnect() explicitly.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, 0 , this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .build();

            // Retrieve the AutoCompleteTextView that will display Place suggestions.
    mAutocompleteView = (DelayAutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);
    mAutocompleteView.setThreshold(3);

    // Register a listener that receives callbacks when a suggestion has been selected
    mAutocompleteView.setOnItemClickListener(mAutocompleteClickListener);

    // Set up the adapter that will retrieve suggestions from the Places Geo Data API that cover
    // the entire world.
    mAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(this, mGoogleApiClient, BOUNDS_GREATER_SYDNEY,
            null);

    //Set Adapter
    mAutocompleteView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    //Set LoadingIndicator
    mAutocompleteView.setLoadingIndicator((android.widget.ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pb_loading_indicator));

    // Set up the 'clear text' button that clears the text in the autocomplete view
    Button clearButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_clear);
    clearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mAutocompleteView.setText("");
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Listener that handles selections from suggestions from the AutoCompleteTextView that
 * displays Place suggestions.
 * Gets the place id of the selected item and issues a request to the Places Geo Data API
 * to retrieve more details about the place.
 *
 * @see com.google.android.gms.location.places.GeoDataApi#getPlaceById(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,
 * String...)
 */
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mAutocompleteClickListener
        = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        //Retrieve the place ID of the selected item from the Adapter.
        //The adapter stores each Place suggestion in a AutocompletePrediction from which we
        //read the place ID and title.

        final AutocompletePrediction item = mAdapter.getItem(position);
        final String placeId = item.getPlaceId();
        final CharSequence primaryText = item.getPrimaryText(null);

        //Issue a request to the Places Geo Data API to retrieve a Place object with additional
        //details about the place.

        PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Clicked: " + primaryText,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};



/**
 * Called when the Activity could not connect to Google Play services and the auto manager
 * could resolve the error automatically.
 * In this case the API is not available and notify the user.
 *
 * @param connectionResult can be inspected to determine the cause of the failure
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    // TODO(Developer): Check error code and notify the user of error state and resolution.
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Could not connect to Google API Client: Error " + connectionResult.getErrorCode(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


}
```

The manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="api_key"/>

    <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".FrameLayout" android:label="@string/app_name"/>

</application>
```

And the log-file:

```
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete, PID: 9065
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3969)
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964)
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete.FrameLayout}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1648)
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1442)
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3511)
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3472)
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3714)
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3682)
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete.MainActivity.ShowIt(MainActivity.java:37)
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132) 
11-17 22:16:54.250 9065-9065/com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't have a clou where the error is located... :-(

Thanks in Advance for your patience.

Comment: `FrameLayout` might be a reserved name in Android, since a class with that name already exists. Try declaring the **full package** name in the manifest: `<activity android:name="com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete.FrameLayout" android:label="@string/app_name"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer, it's not possible to Start a Fragment or a FragmentActivity with an intent brausen the Fragment needs an activity to exist. Just use a fragmentmanager and replace the Fragment in a Containerview.